# Cannot type in terminal window

Tags: command-line, keyboard, raspberrypi, 21.04

I just installed Ubuntu 21.04 arm64 ([ubuntu-21.04-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+raspi.img_2.xz](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/21.04/release/)) on my Raspberry Pi 4B (8G). It runs well initially, but after I update the OS, I cannot type anything in the terminal window.

The cursor in the terminal window is a square which is not blinking. The mouse can click and open the menus of the terminal window such as *Preferences*,  *New WIndow*, etc., but the keyboard cannot type. Typing in other applications works OK

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

PS: Restarting doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like the install is bad.

Comment: To get better experience please try https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/focal/arm64/ubuntu-mate-20.04.1-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz .

Comment: @N0rbert just because Ubuntu20.04 has the same problem, I installed Ubuntu21.04. But thank you all the same!